# Dancing around shul on Rosh Hashanah

Tags: song-poetry, rosh-hashanah-new-year, dance

At my shul, during Musaf of Rosh Hashanah (and i think Yom Kippur as well), they sing the piyut ויאתיו כל to the [Carlebach tune](https://youtu.be/mAmxggRF52I). At the end, a large percentage of the community gets up and starts dancing around the shul.

On a day when [we don't even say hallel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45794/5151), is this appropriate behavior? (Perhaps it depends on your philosophy, Chasidish or Litvak.)

Comment: It is forbidden to dance on Shabbat and Yom Tov. (Mishna Beitza 5:2)

Comment: @DoubleAA I gather that the term "rikud" as used in the mishna is a specific type which involves having both feet off the floor (like "leaping"). I'll see if I can locate an article on this discussion - it's a while since I've read it. Essence of the article is that the form of "rikud" commonly used today (the "yeshivish shuffle") is not in the category of "rikud".

Comment: Rambam writes ([Hil. Megillah 3](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/3a03.htm):6): אבל ראש השנה ויום הכיפורים, אין בהן הלל, לפי שהן ימי תשובה ויראה ופחד, לא ימי שמחה יתרה

Comment: @DoubleAA Well then, what would you call it? "The clap-and-walk-around-the-bima"?

Comment: @Scimonster I'd probably call that Asur.

Comment: @DoubleAA Now I'm curious what Simchat Torah looks like by you.

Comment: @Scimonster http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64313/759

Comment: @DanF Clapping is proscribed too.